# Magento reads/requires htaccess on nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, nginx

We have a magento community install running on nginx, php5 & percona

We manually run indexing from the command line for a solr bridge installed.

We recently hit an out of memory limit of 256MB, which meant the indexing would not complete.

So we increased the value in php.ini, but would still get the issue (mysql restarted etc).

Checking php info, we would see the new correct value of memory_limit report, which is higher than 256MB, but the indexing would alwaysys hit this limit

The only place could find the value of 256MB was in htaccess. Just for fun we set this to 8MB and restarted the index, which then failed at this new limit. Setting the value in htaccess to the value we used in php.ini then allowed the indexer to complete.

Why would htaccess be read by magento when we're using nginx, and will removing it cause no end of other unseen magento issues?

We were under the assumption that nginx made no use of htaccess at all, so why would magento be looking for it?

Comment: That's weird. I'm quite certain nginx could not read .htaccess as it's an apache thingy. Can you do `ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep httpd` to ensure you're not actually running apache? Because what could happen is that you could be running something like apache prefork and just use nginx as the reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks you seth, this has shed some light on the issue seen.

It looks like this is part of the tomcat/java set-up that is being used for the solr bridge we use for magento. We'll do some digging it its required.